# int variable isn't changing VBA PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

i have this code in module1

```
Dim sum As Integer
Sub Wrong()
MsgBox ("Îòâåò íåâåðíûé. ïîïðîáóéòå åù¸ ðàç")
End Sub
Sub Right()
sum = sum + 1
MsgBox ("Âñå âåðíî")
SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
End Sub
Sub RightLast()
MsgBox ("Congratulations!")
End Sub
```

So, when i call a Right function in it doesn't change the "sum". Nani the frick?

Comment: VBA has a built-in `Right` function. Perhaps if you called it something else?

Comment: How are you invoking the `Right` function? If you aren't fully-qualifying it and invoking it from the immediate pane, you're likely calling `VBA.Strings.Right` instead. Does the `MsgBox` show up?

Comment: FWIW these parentheses are redundant/superfluous.

Comment: MsgBox show up without any problem.

Comment: Also tried changing function name, nothing happend.

Comment: Something else must be going on, I can't reproduce the problem with this exact code in a standard module (I'm in Excel so I commented-out the `SlideShowWindows` call and added `Debug.Print sum` after the `MsgBox` in `Right()`). Can you confirm this exact [mcve] produces the problem you're describing in a project that only has this code? FWIW nothing here outputs or consumes `sum` anywhere, so how do you know whether it was incremented or not?

Comment: try this `Public sum As Integer`

Comment: ^ what @horst is saying is that if you're not using `Option Explicit` and checking the value of `sum` from outside that module, then you're really checking the value of an undeclared variable, not that `sum` declaration. If you make it `Public`, then it will be accessible outside the module it's declared in, making it essentially a global variable (which is likely not needed at all... but we don't have enough information to know that).

Comment: Ok, I will try it tomorrow.